# Set up hot reload with parameters with Maven and Spring

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a maven generated project. This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.fsep</groupId>
    <artifactId>abacus-web</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>LOCAL</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>                    
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>            
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.18</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I build it using this command:

```
@mvn package -PLOCAL
```

And run using this command:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=rganeyev target/abacus-web-0.1.jar
```

I have an src/main/resources/application-rganeyev.properties file, where my local properties are set. The application must use this file to work properly.

It works fine, build and running goes ok. The problem is I can not use hot reloading. [Documentation says](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-hot-swapping):

> Developer tools are automatically disabled when running a fully packaged application. If your application is launched from java -jar or if it is started from a special classloader, then it is considered a “production application”.

To use hot-reloading, I mustn't use java -jar, but only mvn utilities. 
I tried to run `mvn spring-boot:run -PLOCAL -Dspring.profiles.active=rganeyev`, but it does not use properties file and crashes. Hot to run maven and use my properties file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi try to add the profile definition to the POM.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <profiles>
                <profile>rganeyev</profile>
            </profiles>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And than call it with the profile:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=rganeyev
```